# Reminder screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]

"I'm currently working on a Proof of Concept (POC) where I'm encountering an issue regarding scheduling alarms or reminders in SwiftUI. I need to display a specific screen with options like a snooze button and an okay button at a scheduled time. However, I'm struggling to find a concept or method in SwiftUI that allows me to present a screen automatically at the scheduled time. Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality in SwiftUI?"

for now at scheduled time i worked with the notification so now i want to replace that notification in to alarm screen as excepted in the above attached file

Comment: maybe this will be useful: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/08/30/lock-screen-widgets-in-swiftui/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Until now, I haven't worked on it. I want to implement this in my POC for reference. Are there any relevant topics?